# What percentage of positive integers, written in base 10, are composite regardless of what base they are interpreted in?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

There is a sequence of numbers (OEIS [A121719](https://oeis.org/A121719)) with the following defenition:

If the string of base-$10$ digits corresponding to the positive integer $k$ is composite when interpreted in any possible base $b$, then $k$ is in the sequence.

After writing a program to find values of the sequence, I was curious whether the percentage of numbers $k<n$ in the sequence approaches a certain value as $n$ increases. I will now formally define my question:

$A$ is the set of all positive integers in the sequence defined above.

$$C(n)=1\:\text{if}\:n\in A,\:\text{otherwise}\:0$$
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} C(i)$$
I would like to know:

1. Does the limit $L$ exist?
2. Is $L>0$?
3. Is there some method to find $L$ or the first $n$ digits of $L$?

Comment: This sequence contains all proper multiples of 10, and also all even numbers $> 2$ with even digit sum (by condition 3 from the link).  Those account for $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ of numbers respectively, with intersection $\frac{1}{20}$, so together that makes at least $32.5\%$ of all numbers.  So $L \geq 0.325$ if it exists (and the same is true of the lower density regardless).

Comment: I'm sure that lower bound can be improved by applying condition 3 with more small primes.  Finding upper bounds sounds much harder.

Comment: By the way, the Bunyakovsky conjecture (or the stronger Bateman-Horn conjecture) would imply that conditions 1-3 are the only "reasons" that a number can be in the sequence; in fact, any number not satisfying any of those conditions should produce infinitely many primes.  But of course these conjectures are currently out of reach.

Comment: @Ravi, why isn't $L > \frac{3}{10} = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ (numbers ending in zero and half of numbers ending in $2,4,6,$ or $8$)?

Comment: @DavidDiaz You're right--thanks for the correction.  (I confused $\frac{1}{20}$ with $\frac{1}{40}$ in my mental calculation.)  Unfortunately I can't edit my comment anymore.

Comment: @RaviFernando You can delete and rewrite a comment :) Bunyakovsky came into my mind as well immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that assuming the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) and the [extended Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis#Extended_Riemann_hypothesis_(ERH)) (i.e. RH for all Dedekind zeta functions), the limit $L$ exists and equals
$$ L = \frac{59/18 + 1/5^4 + 1/7^6}{10} = \frac{4340435807}{13235512500} \approx 0.32793862776. $$
(Both of these hypotheses seem like really big hammers, but I'm pretty sure there is no easy way around either of them.)

Proof:  Identify nonnegative integers $k$ with the polynomials $f_k(x)$ whose coefficients are their base-10 expansions.  The Bunyakovsky conjecture predicts that any $f_k(x)$ not satisfying condition 2 or 3 will produce infinitely many prime values at positive integer inputs.  In particular, it will produce some primes at inputs $b$ which are large enough (say, $b \geq 10$) for $k$ to be interpreted in base $b$.  This implies, conditional on Bunyakovsky, that every term of the sequence must satisfy condition 2 or 3 from the comment on OEIS.

Let's consider condition 3.  Any common divisor of the values of $f_k(x)$ is in particular a divisor of $f_k(0)$, namely the last digit of $k$.  This implies that if the last digit of $k$ is nonzero, $k$ can never satisfy condition 3 for any prime $p > 7$.  Of course, if the last digit of $k$ is zero (and $k > 10$), then $k$ automatically satisfies condition 2.  So it suffices to consider condition 3 with $p = 2, 3, 5$, and $7$, along with condition 2.

Now consider condition 2.  It's relatively uncommon for a polynomial with small integer coefficients to be reducible.  In fact, assuming the extended Riemann hypothesis, Corollary 3 of [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.13360.pdf) of Breuillard and Varjú implies that as $d \to \infty$, the proportion of degree-$d$ polynomials with $\{0, \dots, 9\}$ coefficients that are reducible is $\frac{1}{10} + O(d^{-1/2})$.  (Take $\mu$ to be the uniform distribution on $\{0, \dots, 9\}$ and $N = 1$.  The $\frac{1}{10}$ comes from polynomials vanishing at 0; i.e. integers $k$ that are divisible by 10.)  So as $k \to \infty$, we can ignore condition 2 except as it pertains to multiples of 10.

At this point, it's just a matter of going through the casework of condition 3 for $p = 2, 3, 5, 7$.  You can check that $f_k(x) = \sum_i a_i x^i$ satisfies condition 3 for a given $p$ if and only if the following two hypotheses hold:  (a) $p$ divides $a_0$, and (b) for all $0 \leq t < p-1$, $p$ divides
$$ \sum_{i > 0, i \equiv t \pmod{p-1}} a_i. $$
(Equivalently, $f_k(x)$ lies in the ideal $(p, x^p - x) \subset \mathbb Z[x]$.)  As $k \to \infty$, (b) happens with probability $1/p^{p-1}$, independently of $a_0$.  So the probability that $n$ is in the sequence given each possible last digit is as follows:

0. $P = 1$ (condition 2)
1. $P = 0$
2. $P = 1/2$ ($p = 2$)
3. $P = 1/9$ ($p = 3$)
4. $P = 1/2$ ($p = 2$)
5. $P = 1/5^4$ ($p = 5$)
6. $P = 5/9$ ($p = 2$ or $3$)
7. $P = 1/7^6$ ($p = 7$)
8. $P = 1/2$ ($p = 2$)
9. $P = 1/9$ ($p = 3$)

(Note that for $a_0 = 6$, the conditions coming from $p = 2$ and $p = 3$ are independent as $k \to \infty$.)  Averaging these ten probabilities gives the final answer.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. I am not highly knowledgeable about the extended Riemann hypothesis, though. Which part of this proof requires it to be true?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that.  The results in the Breuillard-Varjú paper are conditional on ERH.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: To be clear, the Breuillard-Varjú paper does all the hard work in this answer.  And my understanding of it goes no further than their results section and the Quanta article:  https://www.quantamagazine.org/in-the-universe-of-equations-virtually-all-are-prime-20181210.

Comment: Well, I was not expecting an exact value for the limit, so I am still delightfully surprised.